# how to execute custom query in dbt

Tags: sql, dbt

I'm trying the customise the incremental model behavior :
I'm testing if table doesn't already existe, I create it,
otherwise I want to run a merge request in which I only merge when values doesn't match (the incremental model update when match, for me i want to keep value as they are when match)
therefor i'm using this

here is my query

```
{% if table_exists %}
merge into {{this}} as DBT_INTERNAL_DEST
    using(
        select 
            * 
        from 
            {{
                source('source', 'dest') 
            }}
    ) as DBT_INTERNAL_SOURCE
on DBT_INTERNAL_DEST.id=DBT_INTERNAL_SOURCE.id
when not matched then insert
        (`col1`, `id`, `col2`)
    values
        (`col1`, `id`, `col2`)

{% else %}

select * from {{source('source','dest')}}

{% endif %}
```

there are some work around that I find, but I think that they are not clean, 
like using `merge_update_columns='id', unique_key = id` (there for when matched, it will update the id column with its value)